# How to construct query to update nested array document in mongo?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am having following document in mongo,

```
  {
   "_id" : ObjectId("506e9e54a4e8f51423679428"),
   "description" : "ffffffffffffffff", 
   "menus" : [  
                {   
                  "_id" : ObjectId("506e9e5aa4e8f51423679429"),     
                   "description" : "ffffffffffffffffffff",  
                      "items" : [
                               {    
                              "name" : "xcvxc",     
                              "description" : "vxvxcvxc",   
                              "text" : "vxcvxcvx",  
                              "menuKey" : "0",  
                               "onSelect" : "1",    
                              "_id" : ObjectId("506e9f07a4e8f5142367942f") 
                              } ,
                              {     
                              "name" : "abcd",  
                              "description" : "qqq",    
                              "text" : "qqq",   
                              "menuKey" : "0",  
                               "onSelect" : "3",    
                              "_id" : ObjectId("507e9f07a4e8f5142367942f") 
                              }
                             ] 
                 },
                 {  
                    "_id" : ObjectId("506e9e5aa4e8f51423679429"),   
                    "description" : "rrrrr",    
                     "items" : [    {   
                                 "name" : "xcc",    
                                 "description" : "vx",  
                                 "text" : "vxc",    
                                 "menuKey" : "0",   
                                "onSelect" : "2",   
                              "_id" : ObjectId("506e9f07a4e8f5142367942f") 
                         } ]
                } 
            ]
   }
```

Now , i want to update the following document :

```
 {  
     "name" : "abcd",   
    "description" : "qqq",  
    "text" : "qqq",     
    "menuKey" : "0",    
        "onSelect" : "3",   
    "_id" : ObjectId("507e9f07a4e8f5142367942f") 
  }
```

I am having main documnet id: **"_id" : ObjectId("506e9e54a4e8f51423679428")** and **menus id
 "_id" : ObjectId("506e9e54a4e8f51423679428")** as well as items id **"_id" : ObjectId("507e9f07a4e8f5142367942f")** which is to be updated.

I have tried using the following query:

`db.collection.update({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "506e9e54a4e8f51423679428"} ,       "menus._id" : { "$oid" : "506e9e5aa4e8f51423679429"}},{ "$set" : { "menus.$.items" : { "_id" : { "$oid" : "506e9f07a4e8f5142367942f"}} , "menus.$.items.$.name" : "xcvxc66666", ...}},false,false);`

but its not working...

Answer (score 1):

The positional operator does not work on the number of levels you are trying to get it to work on ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831?focusedCommentId=22438&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel ) with `menus.$.items.$.name` and even if it did MongoDB query parser would have no idea what the other `$` is from the `find` of the `update`.

You will need to pull out the items from the schema, update that seprately and then update the root document.

One good way of judging when queries should be done separately is to think that each menu sounds like a separate entity (or table in a relational database) as such you should probably work on updating those entites (or tables in a relational model) separately to the parent entity (table).

So first you would get out the main root document. Scroll across it's menus in client side and then `$set` that particular menu to the entire item you build on client side.

#### Edit

The way I imagine this work client side is (in pseudo code since my Java is a little rusty) by first getting that document in an active record fashion:

```
doc = db.col.find({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "506e9e54a4e8f51423679428"} , 
    "menus._id" : { "$oid" : "506e9e5aa4e8f51423679429"}});
```

Then you would iterate through the document assigning your values:

```
foreach(doc.menus as menu_key => menu){
    foreach(menu['items'] as key => item){
        if(item._id ==  { "$oid" : "506e9f07a4e8f5142367942f"}){
            doc.menus[menu_key][key][name] = "xcvxc66666"
        }
    }
}
```

And then simple save the doc after all changes are commited:

```
db.col.save(doc);
```

This is of course just one way of doing it and this way uses the activen record paradigm which I personally like. In this idea you would combine the find with everything else you need to modify on the document, building it up client side and then sending it all down as one single query to your DB.

Comment: thanks sammaye,  I need to do atomic update, is  any other way, i can change the structure also, suggest something which is suitable for me

Comment: @GowtGM Is there a solid requirement that the picking out of the update document and the updating of it must be atomic?

Comment: @GowtGM until hopefully 2.3 (though I should stress, this is not set in stone) this is impossible. The only real way to reduce your schema to one level or use client side updating. But this query still wouldn't work with 2.3 due to the missing find param I talk about. So your gonna need to find another way of doing this

Comment: @GowtGM Wouldn't think so due to the fact that there are multiple items in the menus. I would personally just do this on the client side, pick out the document and use `$set` to atomically set the entire item in the menu to what you build up on client side. It will be fast and efficient, more so than trying to get mutlilevel positional operator working in your case.

Comment: ok thanks, how to do it in client side, i can retrieve the document then what to do?

Comment: @GowtGM I have added one way of doing it client side.

Comment: yes, its working , my app is distributed app, suppose two of them changing the data at a time then issue raises, last updated data only present in database.

Comment: @GowtGM Yea that changes things...hmmm I guess you could wait for 2.3 or you could redo your schema or you could put a lock client side.

Comment: @Sammmaye Suggest some other schema possibilities

Comment: @GowtGM Split out menus array into a separate collection referencing the parent collection. That way items would be only 1 deep and atomic operations would be possible.

Comment: Or, as i said in your other question, introduce a transactionial "thing". 

transactional behavior with a locked flag:
first aquire lock / make sure, that your (the clients) version is the  db version. update the document / a.k.a the "whole" document. and "release" the doc after your changes.


This 'solution' isn't a nice one, and you probably create a new collection etc. but, i am assuming you wont make a lot of changes a sec to that doc/collection. so i wont bug me with a lot of schema redesign if that doc would be changed by human and only once a day etc...

Comment: @Marc Yea that's the same as a client side lock which is a method I suggested however I think the OP decided to do a schema change in the end. Sometimes it is better to just design a schema to be complaint with the DB rather than try and make the client and DB do something it is not designed to do. Transactional behaviour is very expensive and it is better to only rely on the dbs lock in a lot of cases rather than build another one ontop.