# Is it possible to add list of objects into embedded array document in mongo document?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am having the mongo document as below:

```
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("506e9e54a4e8f51423679428"),
  "description" : "ffffffffffffffff", 
  "menus" : [  
            {   
              "_id" : ObjectId("506e9e5aa4e8f51423679429"),     
               "description" : "ffffffffffffffffffff",  
                  "items" : [
                           {    
                          "name" : "xcvxc",     
                          "description" : "vxvxcvxc",   
                          "text" : "vxcvxcvx",  
                          "menuKey" : "0",  
                           "onSelect" : "1",    
                          "_id" : ObjectId("506e9f07a4e8f5142367942f") 
                          } ,
                          {     
                          "name" : "abcd",  
                          "description" : "qqq",    
                          "text" : "qqq",   
                          "menuKey" : "0",  
                           "onSelect" : "3",    
                          "_id" : ObjectId("507e9f07a4e8f5142367942f") 
                          }
                         ] 
             }
         ]
  }
```

Now i want to change this to :

```
       {
        "_id" : ObjectId("506e9e54a4e8f51423679428"),
        "description" : "ffffffffffffffff", 
        "menus" : [ 
            {   
              "_id" : ObjectId("506e9e5aa4e8f51423679429"),     
               "description" : "ffffffffffffffffffff",  
                  "items" : {
                           {    
                          "name" : "xcvxc",     
                          "description" : "vxvxcvxc",   
                          "text" : "vxcvxcvx",  
                          "menuKey" : "0",  
                           "onSelect" : "1",    
                          "_id" : ObjectId("506e9f07a4e8f5142367942f") 
                          } ,
                          {     
                          "name" : "abcd",  
                          "description" : "qqq",    
                          "text" : "qqq",   
                          "menuKey" : "0",  
                           "onSelect" : "3",    
                          "_id" : ObjectId("507e9f07a4e8f5142367942f") 
                          }
                       } 
             }

           ]

   }
```

Is this possible in mongo?  In the first schema, updating is not possible atomically becoz we can't use two "$"  while updating deep layer. So i thought to change schema as same as second one, how can i achieve it?

For first one i have used "$push" for adding **items** inside **menus**...

Any help would be great..

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two? In the second one is there a typo (field names must be strings)? And what is the update that you say is not possible in the first schema?

Comment: In the second form `items` is not a valid Json object. It has to be a key-value pair.

Comment: @Thilo Actually i need to do update atomically , for example:i want to update  "name" : "abcd" to "name":"cc" in items.

Comment: @GowtGM: Then you should probably ask about that. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425993/how-to-update-value-of-specific-embedded-document-inside-an-array-of-a-specifi?rq=1

Comment: @Thilo Yes, but there is no possibility for doing that, i can only update using the index value but i need to do with the id. So i am looking for someother schema..

Comment: @Thilo i need 2 level deep update...

Comment: Updates in Mongo are atomic on Documents. If you need to do two queries and want to make sure that there isnt a change, you might want to create a transaction document to ensure somewhat atomicy over multiple inserts or consider findandmodify + some changes in your app)

Comment: Actually i need answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743125/how-to-construct-query-to-update-nested-array-document-in-mongo

Answer (score 0):

Your update is changing 'menu' object, so I would suggest changing the schema so that the menu is the top level document, rather than an array in another document.

Menu could either have a field referencing the top level object (in another collection) that it belongs to, or you can denormalize the fields of the top level object into each menu document.

Without knowing complete requirements of the application, it's difficult to know when the schema is "good enough".